# How to read the container axis when creating a custom Spacer() in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

In the SwiftUI `Spacer()` documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/spacer
we can see:
*"A flexible space that expands along the major axis of its containing stack layout, or on both axes if not contained in a stack."*

What is the mechanism that is used by the `Spacer` to know if it is inside a `VStack` or `HStack`?

I also see one of the initialisers uses that:

```
init(minLength: CGFloat? = nil)
```

*"The minimum length this spacer can be shrunk to, along the axis or axes of expansion"*

How can I know that "axes of expansion"?

My app has like 5 predefined spacing constants, in an enumeration, and I would like to create a custom initialiser (or static method) that returns a Spacer() with one of my space constants that is used as a min and max at the same time, but in the current axis.

For example, I can do something like:

```
extension Spacer {
    static func spacing(_ spacing: SpaceEnum) -> some View {
        return Spacer().frame(width: spacing.value, height: spacing.value)
    }
}
```

The problem with that, is that the spacer is a square, it doesn't know if we are inside a VStack or HStack.
How can I achieve that?

Ideally, I would like to have something like:

`Spacer(space: .small)`
that inside a VStack does this:
`Spacer().frame(height: SpaceEnum.small.value)`

Or

`Spacer(space: .extraLarge)`
that inside an HStack does this:
`Spacer().frame(width: SpaceEnum.extraLarge.value)`

Any ideas or suggestions?
Maybe, somehow I have to use `GeometryReader` or `alignmentGuide`, I don't know.

Using a square is not a good idea, it is causing issues when if the VStack width is smaller than the space. Or when the HStack height is smaller than the custom space constant.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it is `*Stack` who tells the direction (ex, via private environment values) and taking into account that they have hidden `_HSpacer/_VSpacer` types the `Spacer` itself is just a wrapper who reads env and injects needed concrete implementation.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks a lot for your response. Do you have more info about that? or a link? I would like to explora that approach. Thanks a lot!